# Animating DIV change in height and width

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, height, width

How would I go about animating a div's change in height and width? There would not be an event that would trigger the animation, but an animation that would occur anytime the size of the (this) div changed. The idea is to animate the div's change in size when more or less content is in the div.

Comment: Use [css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: Congrats! the vague question of the day.

Comment: @gdoron: How is the question vague?

Comment: I think the question is "How do I get an event to fire when the content of the element changes, so that I can alter its properties?" @Kevin, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS3 you can set 'transition' property on any element, which will provide you with the effect that you want, without the need to worry about event triggering.

You can specify the **property**, **duration** and **function** (type) of the animation, as shown below:

```
#divWithAnimation
{
    transition: height 1s linear;
}
```

Although the property "transition" is not supported in IE, other browsers use their own prefixes, as follows:

```
#divWithAnimation
{
  -webkit-transition: height 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: height 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: height 1s linear;
  -o-transition: height 1s linear;
  transition: height 1s linear;
}
```

You should use all of these in your stylesheet, in order to provide support for all the available browsers. More info and tutorials about transitions (and other cool features of CSS3) can be found on the [W3Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).

There is a very nice [CSS3 generator](http://css3generator.com/) that can generate the code for all the browsers. Would definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 transitions are the nicest way of doing it for sure - really clean, and you make the browser do the work.  However, if you need support in IE jQuery animate is a good way to go.

It's not as simple as it coule be, since you cannot listen for `resize()` on a div, just a window.

There are some plugins available though, like this one: http://www.jqui.net/demo/mutate/